# How to retrieve the URL including the subdomain through PHP after htaccess rewrite rule?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdomain

I am currently using the code below to retrieve the URL of the current page that the user is on

**PHP**

```
$actual_link = "http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]."";
```

**.htaccess**

The problem with this is that I also have a htaccess rewrite rule which points all subdomains to their directory.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.co [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ http://example.co/%1/$1 [P]
```

For example, if a user visits `test.example.co`, the URL will remain as that but the contents of `example.co/test` will be displayed instead.

As a result of this rewrite rule, if I use the PHP code above, it will return `http://example.co/test` rather than `test.example.co`.

How could I retrieve the exact URL that the user is on?

**Overall**

- The exact URL cannot be retrieved due to a rewrite rule which points all subdomains to their directory
- The path to the directory will be retrieved instead rather than the subdomain
- How could I retrieve the actual URL that the user is on rather than the path it is pointed to?

**Note** - The URL bar still displays `test.example.co` but in fact it just displays the contents of `example.co/test`.

Comment: whether it necessary to use a subrequest with `[p]`?

Comment: @Deadooshka I guess so because otherwise the URL just redirects rather than remaining the same whilst displaying `example.co/subdomain`

Comment: the `mod_proxy` sends some additional headers like a `X-Forwarded-Host` that are visible thru the `$_SERVER`. But if all the subdomains would pointed to the example.co document root, the rule would be the `/%1/$1` with `L`/`END` flag without a `mod_proxy` subrequest.

Comment: @Deadooshka By using L or END, I just get redirected to the document root. Note that the subdomain URL should remain the same whilst displaying the contents of the document root

Comment: I meant without the `http://example.co` prefix, ie `RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /%1/$1 [END]`. The redirect occurs if the replacement string contains either a prefix with `http` or an R-flag. Certainly this is strongly related on overall virtualhost/domain configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've just tried this out and it just leads me to a 404 error for some reason - So I don't think it the subdomain from the URL leads to it being pointed to the directory with that subdomain for the name

Comment: @Deadooshka `/%1/$1` causes a 404 and just `/$1` points you to the directory but you are redirected (including the URL change)